# Rhtml: Warning: conversion failure on '<var>' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <var>

Tags: r, encoding, knitr

**Environment:**

R v. 2.15.1 on Mac OS 10.8.2, platform x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit), with RStudio IDE which is set to use UTF-8 as its default encoding. The OS also uses UTF-8.

```
> Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL")
[1] "sk_SK.UTF-8/sk_SK.UTF-8/sk_SK.UTF-8/C/sk_SK.UTF-8/sk_SK.UTF-8"
```

**Objective:**

Generate an HTML file from the R HTML (.Rhtml) file, containing a plot with extended latin characters, such as š or č.

**Problem:**

When I click on **Knit HTML**, the output looks like this:

```
plot(1:2, main = "šč")
## Warning: conversion failure on 'šč' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for
## 
## Warning: conversion failure on 'šč' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for
## 
## Warning: conversion failure on 'šč' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for
## 
## Warning: conversion failure on 'šč' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for
## <8d>
**Plot with correct characters despite the warnings.**
```

**Question:**

What causes the problem and how to solve it? How can I at least get rid of the warnings which do show in the resulting file?

**Hopeless note:**

I have been searching for a solution for the past hour or two, found many similar cases and tried many different potential solutions (many related to PDF output, which is cocked up the same way if I use just Sweave), and now I am literally hopeless.

**Edit on 9 November 2012:**

The solution using `Encoding()` suggested by @metasequoia does work, but considering the need to print the code as well, preferably without that function, I prefer the solution provided by @nograpes using the function `pdf.options()`.

It is interesting, though, that while

```
<!--begin.rcode
pdf.options(encoding='ISOLatin2.enc')
plot(cars, main="Ťažký")
end.rcode-->
```

produces the same warnings,

```
<!--begin.rcode
pdf.options(encoding='ISOLatin2.enc')
end.rcode-->

<!--begin.rcode
plot(cars, main="Ťažký")
end.rcode-->
```

works as expected. **Why is that?** I thought that chronology is all that matters when running commands in R.

So, the definite solution for my purposes is to put

```
<!--begin.rcode echo="FALSE"
pdf.options(encoding='ISOLatin2.enc')
end.rcode-->
```

in the beginning of each of my codes.

Comment: Probably not wat you are looking for but what about wrapping the plot call in `suppressWarnings`

Comment: Without a reproducible example, I wasn't able to test solutions. However you may consider declaring your encodings with [`Encoding()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Encoding.html)

Comment: @RomainFrancois Thank you for the suggestion. It is useful when I do not have to print out the code, however the encapsulation is also visible if I do. Is there a way to suppress warnings globally?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this problem in Ubuntu. I get a different error in Windows, but similar. Edit your question and give examples of input file (`test.Rhtml`) like: `<!--begin.rcode
plot(1:2, main = "šč")
end.rcode-->` and a command like: `library(knitr);knit('test.Rhtml')` and an example of the output including: `<div class="warning"><pre class="knitr r">## Warning: conversion failure on 'šč' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for
## <c5>`

Comment: This error is related to a problem in the `pdf` device, I believe. You can quickly reproduce the error with `pdf();plot(1:2,main="šč");dev.off()`

Comment: @metasequoia Thank you, I shall experiment with your suggestion tomorrow. Sorry, I am currently very busy.

Comment: @nograpes Thank you as well, it indeed reproduces the problem and I shall thoroughly edit the question just as you suggested tomorrow.

Comment: @HarroldCavendish As I mentioning in my comments, I didn't mean you put the `pdf.options` in the .Rhtml file, but just run it in your session.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer from @metasequoia works, but I wanted to add a few points. If you set the PDF options to a different encoding you won't need to wrap all your output text in `Encoding`. Run this before clicking **Knit HTML**:

```
pdf.options(encoding='ISOLatin2.enc')
```

Ripley talks about encoding issues, especially as the relate to PDFs, in [a post here](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/Rhelp02/archive/91924.html), and it may be of interest. Notably, this error will not occur in the same way on Windows, because encoding is handled in a completely different way.

A different encoding file may be needed for other languages, but this seems to work for Slovak.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the best solution I can use at least for now. Are there any plans to fix the issues in question? For example so that `pdf()` supports UTF-8.

Comment: @HarroldCavendish Check out the post I mentioned in the answer; Ripley mentions that `pdf()` doesn't support UTF-8 because the underlying graphical language doesn't support UTF-8.

Comment: I have read it. Is it possible to upgrade the underlying graphical language, then? Is there even any ongoing development in this area? Excuse my inexperience regarding this topic.

Comment: @HarroldCavendish I think what he means is that PDFs themselves don't support UTF-8. So we have to work around Adobe's choice.

Answer (score 7):

Just to explain the solution you found:

```
<!--begin.rcode
pdf.options(encoding='ISOLatin2.enc')
end.rcode-->

<!--begin.rcode
plot(cars, main="Ťažký")
end.rcode-->
```

This works whereas it does not work when you put the two lines in the same chunk because for each code chunk, `knitr` opens a new graphical device to record plots (by default it is a PDF device). It is too late to set `pdf.options()` because the device has been opened with the default encoding when you put `pdf.options()` and `plot()` in the same chunk.

In the working solution, when the PDF device opens for the second chunk, it inherits the encoding from the setting in the previous chunk; that is how it produces the characters correctly.

If you do not want to set this encoding option in each of your Rhtml file, you can put it in `~/.Rprofile` so it affects all your PDF devices. Or you define your own function to knit Rhtml files, e.g.

```
knit2 = function(...) {
   pdf.options(encoding='ISOLatin2.enc')
   knitr::knit(...)
}
```

Then `knit2('yourfile.Rhtml')`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What I meant was to run `pdf.options(encoding='ISOLatin2.enc')` in your R Session, not include it in the .Rhtml file. I think this is essentially the same as putting it in your `~/.Rprofile`.

Comment: Also, I was wondering if it might make sense to have `knitr` catch these warnings and suggest a solution. You could still output the warning, but add a little message suggesting "You might want to try `pdf.options(encoding='x')`".

Comment: It sounds good to suggest `pdf.options()` automatically, but it is hard to determine `x` here (encoding is a hard issue for me). I think what I can do is to make this an FAQ.

Comment: Hm, you might be able to just point people to the `grDevices/inst/enc/` directory and tell them to find the correct encoding file.

Comment: Yes, I can give a list of possible encodings as you suggested. I mean I'm not sure which encoding would be the correct one to use. Thanks!

Comment: I also get this problem when plotting to PNG instead of PDF. Do you have any idea what may cause this?

Answer (score 3):

Using @nograpes reproducible approximation of an example (R 2.15.1 on Mac OSX):

```
pdf()
plot(1:2,main="šč")
dev.off()
```

I was able to replicate the OP's error code. Wrapping "šč" with `Encoding()` eliminated the warning messages.

```
pdf()
plot(1:2,main=Encoding("šč"))
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works as well, however it is not as convenient as @nograpes solution.