# R plotting a less than or equal to sign and saving to PDF error

Tags: r, pdf

I've been using "\u2264" in many of my plot texts.  (This is a less than or equal to sign).  For instance

```
plot(1:2,main="\u2264")
```

When I try save this graph to a pdf,

```
pdf();plot(1:2,main="\u2264");dev.off()
```

I get an error

```
Warning messages:
1: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on '≤' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <e2>
2: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on '≤' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <89>
3: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on '≤' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <a4>
4: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on '≤' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <e2>
5: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on '≤' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <89>
6: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on '≤' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <a4>
```

What gives?  I think I may need to specify an encoding with pdf.options() but how do I know what encoding to use?

Edit: Forgot to say that I'm on mac osx Mountain Lion

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just doing something like: `plot(1:2,main=expression(phantom(0) <= phantom(0)))`?

Comment: Have you tried the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251665/rhtml-warning-conversion-failure-on-var-in-mbcstosbcs-dot-substituted-f?

Comment: @jongware yes, but it did not work for what I need.