# knitr: cannot create a figure with utf-8 character

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, knitr

The following is my .Rnw file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<myChunk>>=
options(warn = 2)
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
data(BodyWeight,package="nlme")
BodyWeight$temp <- as.character(BodyWeight$Rat)
BodyWeight$temp[BodyWeight$temp == "4"] <- "HI₂"
p <- qplot(Time,weight,data=BodyWeight,colour=temp,geom="line")
direct.label(p,"first.qp")
@

\end{document}
```

The following is how I call knitr from R:

```
library(knitr)
# I have tryied this but doesn't make difference:
# pdf.options(encoding='ISOLatin2.enc')
knit("mwe_knitr.Rnw")
```

I get following as output:

```
> knit("mwe_knitr.Rnw")


processing file: mwe_knitr.Rnw
  |......................                                           |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...........................................                      |  67%
label: myChunk
Quitting from lines 5-13 (mwe_knitr.Rnw) 
Error in grid.Call(L_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto),  : 
  (converted from warning) conversion failure on 'HI₂' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <e2>
```

I tried solutions with encoding, such as posted here:
[Rhtml: Warning: conversion failure on '<var>' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <var>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251665/rhtml-warning-conversion-failure-on-var-in-mbcstosbcs-dot-substituted-f)

(I note in comment above exactly where I try the solution to that problem) but it did not seem to change nothing for me.

I am using R 3.3.1 and knitr package 1.13 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like using the `cairo_pdf` device resolves this issue. In the `setup` chunk below, I set the device option to the `cairo_pdf` device (that's the line that begins `option(device = ...`) and the global chunk option `dev` to default to "cairo_pdf" (in the line that begins `knitr::opts_chunk$set(...`). This approach is discussed in the [`knitr` documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/graphics/) (see the section Encoding of Multibyte Characters) and in [Issue #436](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/436).

I've made a few other changes:

1. Instead of "hard-coding" `"HI₂"` I've used the Unicode symbol for the subscripted 2, `"\U2082"`.
2. Changed the plot call to "standard" ggplot rather than qplot.
3. Changed from calling `directlabels` after making the plot to calling `geom_dl` to add direct labels within the "standard" ggplot workflow.
4. Set the `fontfamily` within `geom_dl`. I found that the subscript 2 was rendered with some font families, but not others.
5. Changed the `warn` option to zero (the default) so that warnings won't be turned into errors. I just did this while I was testing the code, but it can, of course, be set back to 2 if desired.

The chunk `myChunk1a` creates the plot. The chunk `myChunk1b` creates basically the same plot, but in multiple versions, each using a different font family. In these versions, you can see that the subscript 2 is rendered with some font families, but not others. I'm not sure what determines this and the results may be different on your system.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
options(warn = 0)
options(device = function(file, width = 7, height = 7, ...) {
  cairo_pdf(tempfile(), width = width, height = height, ...)
})
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, dev="cairo_pdf")
@

<<myChunk>>=
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)

data(BodyWeight,package="nlme")
BodyWeight$temp <- as.character(BodyWeight$Rat)

BodyWeight$temp[BodyWeight$temp=="4"] = "HI\U2082"

# Change first value so that HI2 label is easily visible
BodyWeight$weight[BodyWeight$temp=="HI\U2082" & BodyWeight$Time==1] = 350
@

<<myChunk1a, fig.height=5>>=
ggplot(BodyWeight, aes(Time, weight, colour=temp)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_dl(method=list("first.qp", fontfamily="Helvetica", cex=1), aes(label=temp)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Helvetica") +
  guides(colour=FALSE)
@

<<myChunk1b, fig.height=11>>=
# Create several plots, each demonstrating a different font family for the labels
grid.arrange(grobs=lapply(c("Helvetica","Courier","Palatino","Times","Serif"), function(f) {
  ggplot(BodyWeight, aes(Time, weight, colour=temp)) + 
    geom_line() +
    geom_dl(method=list("first.qp", fontfamily=f, cex=1), aes(label=temp)) + 
    labs(x="") + 
    theme_bw() +
    theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0), "lines"),
          text=element_text(size=9)) +
    ggtitle(f) +
    guides(colour=FALSE)
}), ncol=1)
@

<<myChunk2, fig.height=5>>=
data(BodyWeight,package="nlme")
BodyWeight$temp <- as.character(BodyWeight$Rat)

# Change first value so that HI2 label is easily visible
BodyWeight$weight[BodyWeight$temp=="4" & BodyWeight$Time==1] = 350

# Set temp==4 to desired expression
BodyWeight$temp[BodyWeight$temp == "4"] <- paste(expression(HI[2]))

# Convert temp to factor to set order
BodyWeight$temp = factor(BodyWeight$temp, levels=unique(BodyWeight$temp))

qplot(Time, weight, data=BodyWeight, colour=temp, geom="line") +
  guides(colour=FALSE) +
  geom_text(data=BodyWeight %>% group_by(temp) %>%
              filter(Time == min(Time)), 
            aes(label=temp, x=Time-0.5, y=weight), parse=TRUE, hjust=1) +
  theme_bw()
@

\end{document}
```

Here's what the plot from `myChunk1a` looks like:

[image]

Comment: +1 thank you for this code. I learned more about ggplot2 from studying it. Unfortunately, I do need the automatic placement that comes with directlabels.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please let me know if the proposed solution works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes using cairo seems to have fixed things. I appreciate also your extra advices.