# What pdf.options(encoding=???,...) is needed for ggsave to work with FontAwesome?

Tags: r, ggplot2, font-awesome

First of all, maybe it is worth mentioning that I'm working on Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.6 (15G1611) and using RStudio 1.0.153 and R version 3.4.1.

I'm trying to integrate FontAwesome into some ggplot2 plots that are saved as PDF using `ggsave`. To that end I have followed multiple online tutorials but so far none have worked for me [but this one](https://rpubs.com/yutannihilation/84208). Here is a self-contained modified version that works. It generates the correct plot on the screen but `ggsave` fails with multiple warnings as shown below.

```
library(extrafont)
library(highlight)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

## download and import font-awesome font
fa_font <- tempfile(fileext = ".ttf")
download.file("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0", destfile = fa_font, method = "curl")
font_import(paths = dirname(fa_font), prompt = FALSE)

## download font-awesome css containing the mapping of font names to codes
fa_css <- tempfile(fileext = ".css")
download.file("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css", destfile = fa_css)
fa_parsed <- css.parser(fa_css)

## create a convenience data frame with names and codes
tmp <- unlist(fa_parsed[str_detect(names(fa_parsed), ":before")])
da_df <- data_frame(char_raw = str_replace_all(tmp,'\"',''),char=str_extract(tmp, "[0-9a-f]+"),char_int=strtoi(char, 16L),codes=str_replace_all(names(tmp),':before.content',''))

## finally run ggplot2 plot using the convenience names and codes df
p <- ggplot(mtcars) +
            geom_text(aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl)),
                      label = intToUtf8(da_df[da_df$codes == 'fa-car','char_int'][[1]]),
                      family = "FontAwesome",
                      size = 12) + theme(legend.position="none")
p
ggsave(filename='test.pdf',plot=p,width=5,height=5)
```

[image: Cars plot]

However, `ggsave` fails and produces the following warnings:

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <ef>
2: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <86>
3: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <b9>
4: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xc0
5: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xea
6: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xbe
7: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0x5f
8: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xff
9: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0x7f
10: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font metrics unknown for character 0x4d
11: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <ef>
12: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <86>
13: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <b9>
14: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <ef>
15: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <86>
16: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <b9>
17: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xc0
18: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xea
19: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xbe
20: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0x5f
21: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xff
22: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0x7f
23: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <ef>
24: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <86>
25: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <b9>
26: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <ef>
27: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <86>
28: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <b9>
29: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xc0
30: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xea
31: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xbe
32: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0x5f
33: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xff
34: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0x7f
35: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <ef>
36: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <86>
37: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <b9>
38: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <ef>
39: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <86>
40: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <b9>
41: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xc0
42: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xea
43: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xbe
44: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0x5f
45: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0xff
46: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font width unknown for character 0x7f
47: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <ef>
48: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <86>
49: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <b9>
50: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <ef>
```

**UPDATE:** According to the comment below it seems that the issue is the bit `label = intToUtf8(...)` and then `ggsave` not understanding the UTF-8 encoding ... the question would then be which encoding can I use while calling `pdf.options(encoding=???)` to solve the issue?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251665/rhtml-warning-conversion-failure-on-var-in-mbcstosbcs-dot-substituted-f) may answer your question.

Comment: Thank you! I doesn't directly but points into the right direction ..