# Include unicode in ggplot in .rmd, render in multiple formats

Tags: r, ggplot2, unicode, r-markdown, knitr

In `ggplot2`, one can include unicode characters in text elements (geoms, axis labels, etc). However, I'm struggling to get these characters to render reliably when ggplot objects are rendered from `.rmd` files into `html_vignette`, `html_document`, and `pdf_document`.

I haven't gotten my issues to be fully reproducible, but at least with this setup:
"Ghost Orchid" Release (077589bc, 2021-09-20) for macOS
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.10 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36",

I'm not able to render the unicode properly when outputting to `.pdf` using the `Knit` button in `Rstudio`

````
---
title: "unicode_in_ggplot"
output: 
  rmarkdown::html_vignette: 
    fig_width: 3
    fig_height: 3
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    fig_width: 3
    fig_height: 3
    fig.retina: NULL
  rmarkdown::pdf_document: 
    fig_width: 3
    fig_height: 3
    latex_engine: xelatex
  word_document: default
vignette: >
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)```


In the `.rmd` file I'd like to be able to render to
`pdf_document`. 

```{r unicode failure}
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(cyl, mpg))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(title= "I can print kappa: \u03ba and ell: \u2113")+
  theme_classic()```
````

This issue has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64471402/8400969) and elsewhere, but the solutions seem pretty specific to just saving `.pdf` files with a `cairo` device. What is a more general way to include unicode characters so they render properly across different output formats, including `pdf_document`.

EDIT:

I fiddled with the `mainfont` field in the `YAML` header, and got a bunch of more informative-looking warnings:

e.g.

```
Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :## conversion failure on 'I can print kappa:  and ell: ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot## substituted for <ce>## Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :## conversion failure on 'I can print kappa:  and ell: ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot## substituted for <ba>## Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :## conversion failure on 'I can print kappa:  and ell: ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot## substituted for <e2>## Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :## conversion failure on 'I can print kappa:  and ell: ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot## substituted for <84>## Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :## conversion failure on 'I can print kappa:  and ell: ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot## substituted for <93>## Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :## conversion failure on 'I can print kappa:  and ell: ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot## substituted for <ce>## Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :## conversion failure on 'I can print kappa:  and ell: ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot## substituted for <ba>## Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :## conversion failure on 'I can print kappa:  and ell: ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot## substituted for <e2>## Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :## conversion failure on 'I can print kappa:  and ell: ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot## substituted for <84>1
```

Comment: Is it an encoding issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13312485/8400969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's (likely) a graphics device issue. You can set a different device using chunk options. If you have the {ragg} package, this usually gives me reliable results.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,
                      dev = "ragg_png")
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```
````

You can also add `dpi = 150` to the options if you find that the graphics are too coarse.

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful! Concern: I imagine including this line would mean adding a dependency to the package if in a package vignette?

Comment: Not a hard dependency. You can put it in 'Suggests' so that continuous integration/CRAN knows what to download but users don't have to install it. We've done this in {geomtextpath} as well.

Comment: I am getting an error on the ubuntu-latest (devel) R installation using GH actions related to this: 

```Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
    conversion failure on 'ℓ = 0' in 'mbcsToSbcs': for ℓ (U+2113)
  Calls: <Anonymous> ... drawDetails -> drawDetails.text -> grid.Call.graphics
  Execution halted```

I do not get the error with the other R installations. Is there anything on the **ragg** end that can deal with this?